# Go support for Scatter-Gather IO operations

Tags: go, io, system-calls, unix-socket

I want to develop a high-performance client-server communication protocol over Unix Domain Sockets in Go. Specifically, I was thinking of employing Vector-IO operations (writev/readv system calls) in order to avoid the overhead of structured data serialization. However, I think Go doesn't fully support the use of scatter-gather io operations. I have found some attempts in providing Go support for writev operations but not readv. Is there a way to implement this in Go and/or what would the alternative be performance-wise?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use [net.Buffers](https://godoc.org/net#Buffers) for optimized batch write using `writev` or similar.

For read, slurp the data up into a single buffer and [slice](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Slice_expressions) the buffer as needed.

Comment: Net? What about files? I need to write multiple pieces of data with `writev()` syscall to disk